# What's the DMA direction for memory-to-memory transfer?

Tags: linux, dma

It seems that the `dma_data_direction` enum is defined for transfer between device and memory:

```
enum dma_data_direction {
    DMA_BIDIRECTIONAL = 0,
    DMA_TO_DEVICE = 1,
    DMA_FROM_DEVICE = 2,
    DMA_NONE = 3,
};
```

Why there is not a direction definition for memory-to-memory (or device-to-device) DMA transfer?

Answer (score 1):

Memory-to-memory DMA transfer mean you "READ" from memory and "WRITE" to memory. In this case the dma_data_direction is DMA_BIDIRECTIONAL.
For other value:

- DMA_TO_DEVICE : mean from memory to device
- DMA_FROM_DEVICE : mean from device to memory

Comment: Then what about device-to-device transfer? Also bidirection? Thx.

Comment: From this documents: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-API-HOWTO.txt
If you absolutely cannot know the direction of the DMA transfer,
specify DMA_BIDIRECTIONAL.  It means that the DMA can go in
either direction.  The platform guarantees that you may legally
specify this, and that it will work, but this may be at the
cost of performance for example.